# How to make executable metro style apps?

Tags: xaml, exe, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I Created Metro style Application ,and i want to make it executable so that i can run it on devices that have windows 8, is there any tutorials or tool that make that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to package the app (Project -> Store -> Create app package) to either upload it to the store or use it locally, the second being what you want. The computer you want to run the app on then needs to have a developer license.